# Copying rows containing a string from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel, rows

I found this piece of code that searches through the H column in a sheet and copies the cells which contain the word "apply" in a new workbook.
I then tried to change it so it would copy the entire row, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, as it now just opens a new workbook and leaves it empty.
Can someone look at the code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Many thanks

```
Sub test()

    Dim K, X As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
    K = 1
    X = 5
    Dim w1 As Workbook, w2 As Workbook
    Set w1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set w2 = Workbooks.Add
    w1.Activate
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("H:H"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        X = X + 1
        If InStr(v, "applied") > 0 Then
            '**Initial line** - r.Copy w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(K, 1)
            With w2
            w1.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("X:X").Copy .Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("K")
            K = K + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your code.

- You are using strings for row references.  "X:X" will resolve to the string X:X.  It will not substitute the value of X inside the string.  Same for "K" on sheet 2.
- you are copying the row five below the row in which you find "applied".

If you want to copy the same row, I would suggest:

```
Dim K, X As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
K = 1
Dim w1 As Workbook, w2 As Workbook
Set w1 = ThisWorkbook
Set w2 = Workbooks.Add
w1.Activate
For Each r In Intersect(Range("H:H"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = r.Value
    X = X + 1
    If InStr(v, "applied") > 0 Then
       r.EntireRow.Copy w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(K)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next r
```

You could also change the Copy line to:

```
r.EntireRow.Copy w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(K, 1)
```

but I don't know if the one is more efficient than the other.